How can i secure my redis instance which is hosted on render
I'm using a Redis database hosted on Render, and my backend is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which comes with a load balancer. The problem is that I want to secure the connection between the Redis database and the load balancer's DNS. However, Redis on Render only allows IP-based access control, and I don’t have a static IP only a DNS from the load balancer.
As a workaround, I've had to expose the Redis database to the public (0.0.0.0/0), which isn't secure. I'm looking for a way to secure the database so that only requests from the load balancer are allowed, despite not having a static IP.
Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how I can resolve this and make the connection secure?

Outgoing traffic doesn't go through the load balancer as far as I know. It will go from either you resources themselves (EC2 instances or what do you have?) if they are in a public subnet or via a NAT Gateway if not. Do you have a NAT Gateway?

Yes, we are using EC2 instances, and these are in a private subnet. We also have NAT gateways set up for them.

So then the IPs you should whitelist should be your NAT Gateway(s) IP address(es).
